# Getting character to jump in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have tried using a KeyListener to make the character rise which just simply didnt do anything. Is there a better way to do this? If not, does anyone know why the KeyListener isn't working? I would really appreciate some help. Also, I call this method in a Timeline so the bird does not just fall 1 pixel and will not rise by one either

Here is the code for the KeyListener (The bird falling part works fine by the way):

```
public static void birdJump() {

        birdView.relocate(100, fall++);
        if(fall > 201)
        birdView.setRotate(50);

        FlappyBird.root.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getCode().equals(32)) {

                    birdView.relocate(100, fall--);
                    if(fall > 199)
                    birdView.setRotate(-50);

                }
            }
        });
     }
```

Thanks!

Comment: How could `event.getCode().equals(32)` ever be true? `event.getCode()` is not even numeric.

Comment: 32 is the key code for space @James_D

Comment: I know the ASCII code for a space (which represents a character, not a key). The ASCII code has nothing to do with  `event.getCode()`, which does not even return an int. Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCode--)

Comment: You should do it like this if space key is pressed.  event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.SPACE);

Answer (score 2):

Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCode--): `event.getCode()` does not return an `int` (or a number of any kind), so `event.getCode().equals(32)` cannot possibly be `true`.

You want

```
if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what James_D said, I think it's because you use the `KeyEvent` on a Layout that does not have the focus by default since it belongs to the `Scene`, to remedy it you have to give it the focus :

```
root.setFocusTransversale(true); /* Enable focus on the layout */
root.requestFocus();  /* give the focus to the layout */
```

I hope this will solve your problem !

Comment: Probably true too. Of course there may also be other things wrong we're not aware of. I should probably just have voted to close the question as there is not sufficient information in it, instead of answering. Prepare for a flood of "but it still doesn't work" comments...

Comment: So what information would you like? Rather than being rude like that you could just say what other information you think is needed.

Comment: @Jackfor Rather than creating a second account and reposting a [question you have already posted under a different account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722949/eventhandler-not-performing-action-needed), you should edit the existing question and provide the information that you were already asked for there.

Comment: I wasnt asked for extra information, i was criticised for a 1 character mistake

Comment: @Jackfor I said (twice) "Please edit the question so that it includes a [MCVE]". The point is that if you do that, then people can see any and all causes of why it's not working.

Comment: What isnt Minimal, complete or verifiable about what was provided?

Comment: Directly quoted from the link in the previous comment: "Complete.

Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included:

Some people might be prepared to load the parts up, and actually try them to test the answer they're about to post.
The problem might not be in the part you suspect it is, but another part entirely." So in the case of JavaFX you would provide an actual `Application` subclass that others can copy, compile, and run ("Complete"), that compiled successfully and reproduced the error ("Verifiable"). "Minimal" means you have just enough to do that.

Comment: You simply could have said you wanted enough to be able to test it. Minimal would imply that just where the issue is would be needed

Comment: @Jackfor  But you don't know what caused the issue, or you wouldn't be asking... As pointed out in this answer, there may be causes that are not associated with the code you have posted. I provided a link that defined the terms "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable", carefully and clearly.